# How To Use Custom Form Style

Tags: react-admin

How can we use a different style for forms ?

For example, how to use the horizontal forms like Bootstrap :

[Bootstrap Horizontal Forms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#horizontal-form)

Answer (score 0):

React Admin comes with two built-in forms:

- [SimpleForm](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#the-simpleform-component) ([source](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/be0d5acbdd768d9c8407a36968d2630bc92ec2ab/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/form/SimpleForm.js)): Simple vertical form using Material UI
- [TabbedForm](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#the-tabbedform-component) ([source](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/be0d5acbdd768d9c8407a36968d2630bc92ec2ab/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/form/TabbedForm.js)): Same, but with tabs

You can customise these form by [overriding their style props](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#overriding-a-component-style) or [write your own components](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component) by copying the sources.

It's just React and plain javascript, feel free play with them!